# How to put a button in notification?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a button into notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330592/how-to-add-a-button-into-notification)

Can we put buttons in notification and how to listen to the onclick event?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can, 2) You can't. It is impossible to listen on events. Instead that, launch an Intent from notification.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, notifications are itself clickable. The main goal of every notification is to notify your user, that your application wants him to pay attention to it. So the best scenario is to redirect the user to your application on the notification's click and to proceed inside your app. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!My technique sucks...

Comment: @user898366, You just need to read the documentation carefully