# How to add a button into notification?

Tags: android, galaxy, android-notifications

I do it like this:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(..);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1,pd);
noti.contentviews = views;
```

and then notify the notification.
I can see the button in the notification,
but the button can't be clicked.
When i click the button,the whole notification clicked!
How can i resolve this question?
I found everywhere for this,but nothing useful found.
someone said, some phones don't support the notification button,
 but samsung galaxy s, the musicplayer's notification has button click event.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270928/how-to-put-a-button-in-notification/7270981#7270981

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put interactive widgets, like a `Button`, in a `Notification` and get user input from them. These are for output display only.

Comment: but why galaxy s musicplayer does?

Comment: @Tony: That is part of device firmware. They can cheat. You and I can't.

Comment: @CommonsWare It's a shame! So the picture with buttons http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#interacting-with-notifications is fake or firmware-supported ?

Comment: @midnight: Jelly Bean supports buttons, via a firmware-controlled mechanism. Prior releases do not.

Answer (score -1):

We can made custom notification and put buttons into that and also can perform different functionality on that onClick function, recently I was stuck in the same problem but this link

[Handling buttons inside android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications)

save my life.

You can also see my code here 
[Adding button action in custom notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification)

and it actually works on my HTC Sensation XE havent tried on other devices yet. So cheer and good luck