# Adding button action in custom notification

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-notifications

I have made `custom notification` and there is a button in that, I want to perform two different `functionalities on notification and button click`. I look at many links but couldn't find the way to add button listener.

Can anyone help. Here is my code. Thanks a lot.

```
 private void startNotification() {
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pIntent;
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.mynotification);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContent(
            remoteViews);

    if (hasFlash) {
        intent = new Intent(context, FlashLight.class);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, 0);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(context, BlankWhiteActivity.class);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, 0);
    }
    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)      getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notif = builder.setContentTitle("Flashlight")
            .setContentText("Lighten your world!!!").build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash, pIntent);

}
```

I have passed the button id (`closeOnFlash`) in `setOnClickPendingIntent` don't know why its not working.

And here is my `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notifiation_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:contentDescription="@string/appImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/flashLightOn"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/closeOnFlash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="@string/close" />
```

Comment: May be this thread helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479165/event-onclick-for-a-button-in-a-custom-notification

Comment: This thread should answer what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications

Comment: Actually the second one really worked for me on my HTC sensation, havent checked the compatibility issues.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Start notification as:

```
private void startNotification(){
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, null, 
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.mynotification);

    //the intent that is started when the notification is clicked (works)
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, FlashLight.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    //this is the intent that is supposed to be called when the 
    //button is clicked
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
            switchIntent, 0);

    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash, 
            pendingSwitchIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}


public static class switchButtonListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Here", "I am here");
        FlashOnOff flashLight;
        flashLight = new FlashOnOff();
        flashLight.flashLightOff();
        flashLight.releaseCamera();         
    }
}
```

xml used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/notifiation_image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:contentDescription="@string/appImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/flashLightOn"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/closeOnFlash"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="@string/close" />
```

In manifest under Application tag:

```
<receiver android:name="FlashLight$switchButtonListener" />
```

Comment: How does the declaration in Manifest work ? Is FlashLight your class containing the swiftButtonListener ? Is it the application name ?

Comment: This is really a great idea! Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: @ShaikMDAshiq yes it is the class containing the receiver you may also use fully classified name of the class

Comment: Is this considered a **global Broadcast** that it has to be declared in the Manifest?  If not, why can't it be used as a **LocalBroadcast**?

Comment: How to change notification button in receiver

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi How to change notification button programatically after click on that notification button?

Comment: @rams use notification id to get notification and replace notification by generating it again i think this could be one way to do that

Comment: here my requirement is play/pause button need to change without generating new notification

Comment: keep the instance of the button globally and change it, see if it works

Comment: here how to add another button click

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi How to add another button click in notification

Comment: Is it possible or not?

Comment: @rams it is possible add an other button in xml and write it's on click listener

Comment: @rams thumbs up