# How to create onclick events to custom Android notifications

Tags: android, notifications, onclicklistener

I am new to Android. Presently I was using custom layouts for notifications.
I want to know how to give clickable actions when button clicked on notification bar.
In my project, I was using 2 buttons in notifications. When user clicks on one of the button I have to get a method from another class.
How can I implement it ?

So I have to work with two on clickable events here.

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding button action in custom notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification)

Comment: add some code to the question